# Get facebook ratings reviewer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

How retrieve reviewers from reviews.
I check this
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/open-graph-rating/
and tryed to use "reviewer" field, but got nothing. All another fields work fine.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you need the reviewer for?

Comment: I wanna post reviews from my FB page on my website

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your app running. You are probably using a test version or an app in dev mode.